# Non-scrollable ListView inside of a scrollable parent layout

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

Using Android Studio, I have the following layout:

[image]

The three list items on the bottom are `ListView` objects and they are all inside of a `RelativeLayout` object which is inside of a `ScrollView` object. I would like the three list view objects to have a layout height that wraps content and not be scrollable. If the height of the three list objects extends beyond the bottom of the screen, I want the `RelativeLayout` to become scrollable but not the `ListView` objects.

[image]

And if you want it, here is the code for this activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/root_padding"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CourseViewActivity">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_display"
            android:text="@string/course_view"
            android:textSize="@dimen/header_text_size"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/edit_course_button"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/edit_course_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/date_display"
            android:text="@string/start_and_end_dates"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/edit_course_button"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/edit_course_button"
            android:layout_below="@id/title_display"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mentor_display"
            android:text="@string/course_mentor_display_default"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/edit_course_button"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/edit_course_button"
            android:layout_below="@id/date_display"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/credits_display"
            android:text="@string/course_credits_display_default"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/edit_course_button"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/edit_course_button"
            android:layout_below="@id/mentor_display"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/passed_display"
            android:text="@string/passed"
            android:textColor="#128039"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sub_header_text_size"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_above="@id/separator"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/edit_course_button"
            android:text="@string/edit_course"
            android:onClick="editCourse"
            android:background="@color/blue_button_bg"
            android:textColor="@color/blue_button_fg"
            android:padding="@dimen/button_padding"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/separator"
            android:layout_below="@id/credits_display"
            android:background="#333"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_below="@id/separator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/objective_header"
            android:text="@string/objectives"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sub_header_text_size"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/create_objective_button"
            android:onClick="createNewObjective"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/objective_header"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/objective_list"
            android:layout_below="@id/objective_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/assessment_header"
            android:text="@string/assessments"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sub_header_text_size"
            android:layout_below="@id/objective_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/create_assessment_button"
            android:onClick="createNewAssessments"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/assessment_header"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/assessment_list"
            android:layout_below="@id/assessment_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/note_header"
            android:text="@string/notes"
            android:textSize="@dimen/sub_header_text_size"
            android:layout_below="@id/assessment_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/create_note_button"
            android:onClick="createNewNote"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/note_header"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/note_list"
            android:layout_below="@id/note_header"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT:
The project needs to be API 15 which means I can't use things like `RecyclerView`.

Comment: "I would like the three list view objects to have a layout height that wraps content and not be scrollable" -- then do not use `ListView`. Use a `ConstraintLayout` or `LinearLayout` wrapping the individual "list" rows. Or, get rid of all of this and use a single `RecyclerView` that contains all of your scrollable content.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the project needs to be API 15 which means I can't use things like `RecyclerView`. As for using a `LinearLayout` instead of a `ListView`, I think that might be the way I will need to go, but I'm not sure how to do it, but I can figure it out. I was just hoping there was an easy way to do it like with the `ListView`.

Comment: "I forgot to mention that the project needs to be API 15 which means I can't use things like RecyclerView." -- [`RecyclerView` works back to API Level 14](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/recyclerview/recyclerview/1.0.0/).

Comment: ScrollView should have fix layout so it not advisable to use `wrap_content` on height try changing it to `match_parent` also ListView lost it ability to be scrolled once it is inside the scrollview that is the common scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Your xml code is right but needs some changes check below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".SwipeRefreshLayoutActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title_display"
                android:text="@string/course_view"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/edit_course_button"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/edit_course_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date_display"
                android:text="@string/start_and_end_dates"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/edit_course_button"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/edit_course_button"
                android:layout_below="@id/title_display"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mentor_display"
                android:text="@string/course_mentor_display_default"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/edit_course_button"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/edit_course_button"
                android:layout_below="@id/date_display"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/credits_display"
                android:text="@string/course_credits_display_default"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/edit_course_button"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@id/edit_course_button"
                android:layout_below="@id/mentor_display"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/passed_display"
                android:text="@string/passed"
                android:textColor="#128039"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_above="@id/separator"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/edit_course_button"
                android:text="@string/edit_course"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/separator"
                android:layout_below="@id/credits_display"
                android:background="#333"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:text="Objectives"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_arrow_left"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list_objectives"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:text="Assessments"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_arrow_left"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list_assessments"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:text="Notes"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_arrow_left"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list_notes"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

To `Scroll` multiple listviews in scroll view  add below code in java file:

```
 public void setListViewHeight(ListView listView) {
        ArrayAdapter listAdapter = (ArrayAdapter) listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter != null) {
            int totalHeight = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
                listItem.measure(0, 0);
                totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
            }

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
            listView.setLayoutParams(params);
            listView.requestLayout();
        }
    }
```

**How to invoke above method in java file:**

After set the `adapter` to `listview` invoke method like below:

```
 final ListArrayAdapter adapter3 = new ListArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList3);
    listAssessments.setAdapter(adapter3);
    setListViewHeight(listAssessments);
```

I hope it works for you.